# I uploaded a Kindle book. How can I view the book description prior to publishing?

Tags: kindle

I want to publish a Kindle book. I uploaded both the description and content. However, I can´t find the description on the Amazon Kindle page for review before publishing. I can see the content but not the description. Any ideas?